# Why combining insert sort and quick sort get worse result?

Tags: python, quicksort

I tried to set a cutoff to combine quick sort and insert sort which using insert sort when n(number of data to sort) is lower than cutoff. However, I found the method didn't work and even worse than before. Why and how to imporve it?

To sort 10e4 random int number, the quick sort with a cutoff(50) takes 0.6s and the method without a cutoff takes only 0.02s.

The quick sort with a cutoff(50):

```
def quick_sort(line, l, r):
    if r - l > 50:
        pivot = find_median(line, l, r)
        i, j = l+1, r-2
        while True:
            while line[i] < pivot:
                i += 1
            while line[j] > pivot:
                j -= 1
            if i < j:
                line[i], line[j] = line[j], line[i]
                i += 1
                j -= 1
            else:
                break
        line[i], line[r-1] = line[r-1], line[i]
        quick_sort(line, l, i-1)
        quick_sort(line, i+1, r)
    else:
        insert_sort_index(line, l, r)


def find_median(line, l, r):
    center = (l + r) / 2
    if line[l] > line[r]:
        line[l], line[r] = line[r], line[l]
    if line[l] > line[center]:
        line[l], line[center] = line[center], line[l]
    if line[center] > line[r]:
        line[center], line[r] = line[r], line[center]
    line[center], line[r-1] = line[r-1], line[center]
    return line[r-1]


def insert_sort_index(line, l, r):
    if l < r:
        for idi in range(l+1, r+1):
            data = line[idi]
            for idj in range(idi+1)[::-1]:
                if idj >= l+1 and line[idj-1] > data:
                    line[idj] = line[idj-1]
                else:
                    break
            line[idj] = data
```

The method without a cutoff:

```
def quick_sort(line, l, r):
    if r - l > 1:
        pivot = find_median(line, l, r)
        i, j = l+1, r-2
        while True:
            while line[i] < pivot:
                i += 1
            while line[j] > pivot:
                j -= 1
            if i < j:
                line[i], line[j] = line[j], line[i]
                i += 1
                j -= 1
            else:
                break
        line[i], line[r-1] = line[r-1], line[i]
        quick_sort(line, l, i-1)
        quick_sort(line, i+1, r)
    else:
        if r == l + 1:
            if line[l] > line[r]:
                line[l], line[r] = line[r], line[l]
```

Comment: What's the complexity of insert_sort?

Comment: O(n^2), however, when the data size is small, insert sort  is almost equal to quick sort.

Comment: Your cutoff is just too low. You might be interested in the analysis in https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listsort.txt, which among other things decides when to use insertion sort vs something more complicated by *asymptotically* (not absolutely) faster.

Comment: You could have provided a quick test framework, but didn't. In find_median, center is not found by integer division. Is that a python3 vs python2 difference? In quick_sort, the cutoff is triggered by difference of 50, but only handles difference of 1. Does this even sort?

Comment: @chepner When I increase the cutoff, the algorithm takes longer time.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I has corrected the code. It works when I replace the range function with while.

Comment: I deleted my comment about range because I'm having trouble proving it, but range can be pretty inefficient in python2, especially with that reverse splice (range can take a step argument). Do you mean it performs better now?

Comment: @KennyOstrom Yes, it performs better without range function in insert sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python3 implements range and other functions as iterators/generators, so it would probably be much more efficient in this application, but the python2 range function creates a complete list in memory. You use range multiple times insert_sort_index (and create another list with the [::-1] splice. You could have passed step as an argument to range for that one).

My python2 implementation seems to be optimizing for loops with range(0,x) which made it harder to demonstrate the problem, but not when (l, r) is within a larger list, as is the case with this quicksort cutoff.

I measured aprox. double speed of the insert sort, when operating on a range of a larger list, by using a while loop for idi, idj instead of range().

Comment: Couldn't xrange() be used instead of range(). It won't generate a list, but it will need to keep track of the start, current, and ending values.

Comment: @rcgldr Yes, xrange() also better than range, and performs like using while.